# Is it possible to generate a complete, working WPF/Silverlight/XAML application that emits best practices?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

Is there a way, given a database or some other source specification for an application, for an entire WPF or Silverlight / XAML application to be generated that emits best practices?

For example, assuming I have a well-normalized database (or some other kind of base specification for an app), is there a tool that can create a well-formed MVVM application.  This would include...

- XAML (Views) for all of the tables (list and edit) with no code-behind
- ViewModels that emits properties extracted from the db schema along with commands or behaviors for all of your standard CRUD operations
- Models built with the repository pattern (or some other db abstraction) with interfaces that emit the table design and relationships and a default implementation of your choice (sql, sql ce...whatever).

An ideal tool like this would only do a "first pass" of the application after which the developer would make all necessary changes and modifications.

I don't think there is any such tool but it seems like a tool like this should be possible.

Another related question, in the absence of such a tool (or even if there is one), what tool(s) are best used to get me from a database design (or some other kind of base specification for an app) to working app.

What STEP-BY-STEP process do you take to get from design to basic working application in a couple of hours?

I am just trying to figure all of these practices and patterns and I am getting a pretty good grasp of the pieces but not sure what workflow to use to make it all work together quickly but still allows unit testing of separate concerns.

Thanks in advance.

Seth

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can use [LightSwitch](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From a process perspective, I build and test my ViewModels first. That allows a division of labor between designing and wiring up the UI and pulling data into the ViewModel.

Comment: Chris,  at the heart of this question is wondering why, when someone has a database, would they EVER have to write data access code.  And, of course, with EF you really DON'T have to write a DAL.  But, in keeping up with what you have taught me, I have had trouble figuring out how to use EF AND still allow the ViewModel to be testable using a mock dal, like a respository.   (Apparently it is a common criticism of EF from the ALT.NET crowed. )

Comment: And for me, understanding a pattern is not enough (I am coming along in that regard).  I want to understand a "workflow".  Sort of a step by step process that will help me implement all the pieces in a way that is testable.  In our discussions we have not much discussed integrate mock data and maybe we could focus on that next time.

Comment: Finally, I am surprised that, given a database schema, there is not a tool that builds your entire app in a way that is testable as a starting point.  I know it is not very TDD and my assumption is that the developer would wrap the generated code after the fact and after that would use a TDD approach.  I know at some point we have to write code but the more we can focus on business logic and less on plumbing the better.  Thanks for all you do.  Seth

Comment: Sounds good. Part of the point of the repository pattern is specifically to allow for mock data. IRepository is usually a layer of abstraction over the chosen ORM, so choosing EF or NHibernate or some other ORM shouldn't impact the way data is gathered for a ViewModel. I agree that it would be nice to have some WPF -> DB scaffolding.

Comment: Chris, you said "choosing EF or NHibernate or some other ORM shouldn't impact the way data is gathered for a ViewModel".  And yet that is exactly what I have been trying to figure out.   If I use EF or NH or any other ORM, doesn't it have to implement IRepository interfaces in order swap in mosks for unit testing?  And yet I have not found a simple way to do that.  Specifically, how do you setup your DAL to use EF for example, but then swap in IRepository mocks for testing if EF does not implement IRepository pattern?  I don't quite get?   I'm probably making it too hard.

Comment: It's going to be easier if we work through a sample. Generally speaking, you define your own repository interface and provide an implementation against your chosen ORM. We can do that pretty quickly. Email me when you want to meet up next.